# UITableView display search results in separate tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am implementing real-time searching of a UITableView. I would like to display the results in a separate table view (in it's own UITableViewController class). Is there a way to simply replace one tableview with another once the user begins typing in the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to UISearchDisplayController. It will surely provide what you require :)

Comment: I think this might work, thanks ... I currently have a UIViewController with a search bar and a ui table view, can this be the UISearchDisplayController as well? The other UITableView I need is in a separate UITableViewController class

Answer (score 0):

Create two tableViews, tableList and tableSearchResults. Also declare one more tableView namely, tableCurrent. Initially make tableCurrent to point to tableList, then load the objects into tableCurrent. You can use this (tableCurrent) to display contents and handle selection events.When user fishes searching, assign tableCurrent to tableSearchResults, and then load objects from search results array. This will make two table views, one for Listing and other for search reasults...

Happy programming

Answer (score 0):

There is little reason to use two actual tableViews, if only one is visible at a time. You could just change the `.dataSource` and `.delegate` properties. (If they are sized and styled the same anyway.)